# Responsive site problem, when i resize my screen section that goes after the hero goes upper

Tags: css, sass

I have problem when i resize my screen section that goes after hero section start going upper i realize that problem is background overlay where i use position absolute to set background image on hero and navbar. Is there any solution to this problem.

```
.bg-overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url(../img/bgHero.jpg) center center;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I am expecting that when i resize my screen section after hero does not go upper.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you read both "*[ask]*", and "*[mcve]*" in order to understand both what we expect of a question, and why this question can't be answered in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem you could change the `.bg-overlay` class to have a position of fixed and you can use `z-index` to set it to be in the background or in the front. I do not have enough info to fully answer this question though, please give more info if you ever write another stack overflow question.

Comment: i would provide your more information, but without looking into my code i think it is hard to answer properly but in short i am using boostrap and i want picture to show on navbar menu and hero section which i did with solution i posted but i have a problem that i already explained so can you please give me some tips how to to this, some picture is showing on navbar and menu, and i if set fixed instead absolute then it show all over the page so that is not solution. Thanks for answering, i will try something else